# Sharing state among subcomponents in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm currently developing an **app that uses React in some parts of its UI** to implement some complex feature that are very interactive. Some of these parts of the app, that are in fact React components, have become very complex in size.

This has led me to organize the code by dividing them in **multiple subcomponents** (and those in their own subcomponents, and so forth). The main problem is that **some of the grandchildren of the main component might have the need to modify the state of another grandchildren that they're not related to**. To do so, I end up having to have the state in the common parent and passing a lot of event handlers (methods of the parent component) to their children, and those children would need to pass it to their grandchildren.

As you can imagine, this is becoming some kind of a mess.

```js
// MyComponent.js
class MyComponent extends React.Component  {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      selected: '',
    }

    this.add = this.add.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  add() {
    const newNumber = this.state.list[this.state.list.length - 1] + 1,
    list = [...this.state.list, newNumber]
    this.setState({list})
  }

  handleChange({target}) {
    this.setState({
      selected: target.value,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>
          <List items={this.state.list} selected={this.state.selected} />
          <Button onClick={this.add} />
          <input type="text" value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </>
      )
  }
}
```

```js
// Button.js
class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click me!</button>
        );
    }
}
```

```js
// List.js
class List extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.refs = props.items.map(_ => React.createRef())
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.items.map((item, key) =>
                    (<li ref={this.ref[key]} key={key}>{item}</li>)
                )}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

In the previous dummy code you can see how I need to define the `add()` method in the `MyCompoent` component so that an action that happens in the `Button` component can modify what is being shown in `List`. Even tho this might seem like the obvious way to do it, my component has a big component tree, and a lot of methods, and most of then are lost in the tree, passing from parent to child until it reaches the component that should be expected.

I have done some research on the internet and it turns out this is a very common problem. In most sites, using Redux or other state management library is recommended. However, **all the tutorials and guides I've seen that implement Redux with React seem to assume you're only using React** to build your app, in Single Page Application sort of way. This is not my case.

Is there any way to share the state of a component to avoid this kind of problem? Is there, maybe, a way to use Redux multiple times for **multiple components in the same app**, where one store saves only the state for `MyComponent` and can be accessed by either `List` or any of its possible children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Redux doesn't require your entire site to be in React. It implements a higher-level component that you can use with any React components even if they are embedded in another site.
2. You can look at React hooks to solve similar problems. Specifically, check out `useContext()` and `useState()`.

Answer (score 3):

You've used a [lifting state up pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in react in your example.

It's quite common you good approach but when you app is growing you need to pass all bunch of props throu the tree of components. It's difficult to maintain.

In this case you need to check out *redux* with separated store or *useContext()* hook.